# Are there modules to dynamically map a csv file to an object in Python? I.e. Is there a python version of C#'s CsvHelper?

Tags: python, csv

This is what I'm talking about. [Link](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started).

So I want to map the values of a csv to the attributes of a class. The classes are dynamic, and so I don't want to put it in the `__init__` method and pass the values in. Plus the order of the columns in the csv is not always going to be the same.

Here is some code that I've drawn up that actually does what I want.

```
import csv

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'a: {self.a} b: {self.b}'

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace = True)
    tests = []
    headers = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        t = Test()
        for i in range(len(headers)):
            print(headers[i])
            if hasattr(t, headers[i]):
                setattr(t, headers[i], row[i])
            else:
                raise Exception("csv header does not match")
        tests.append(t)
print(tests)
```

My csv is the following

```
a, b
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
```

And I successfully print `[a: 1 b: 2, a: 3 b: 4, a: 5 b: 6]`

But I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, and there are some other functionalities of CsvHelper I would like, so are there any similar libraries in Python? I couldn't really find anything.

Comment: You will need to tell what you actually want to achieve. People skilled in Python can do classes for this sort of thing in < 30 lines of code, and there is no need for an external CSV library, besides the built-in CSV module to the the actual complicated quoting corner-cases in CSV reading/writting.

Comment: with "to achieve", I man the "some other functionalities ... I would like",

Comment: Well, on the first link there are already a few things. Being able to define a custom column name instead of using just the attribute name, using index numbers instead of the attribute names, ignoring attributes, and writing to a csv file. I'm not asking for someone to implement these things, but rather I just want to see if something has already been implemented so I don't have to spend time doing this.

Comment: This extra functionality is not in the stdlib - a place to search for it is on "pypi.org" . A nice library that can read and write CSV and do what-you-want to tabular data is Pandas - although it won't give you attribute-like access to values by itself. The builtin CSV module  can read each line as a dictionary. To have access to attributes either by column name or by Index, can be done with Pandas. "fixing the case" of column names is lipstick, and you'd have to code that (str.title() does that, but then you have to transform all read records explicitly to match the transformed name)

Comment: TL;DR: if you just need an elegant class to wrap your csv records, it would be  a nice python-teaching/learning exercise. If you have a goal, and just want to grind your data and get your output - go for Pandas!